# Print a list as a table in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a list like this:

```
[[A,0,1],[A,0,0],[B,0,1],[C,1,1],[C,0,1]]
```

and i would like to print it in html like this:

```
-------------
| A | 0 | 1 |
-   -   -----
|   |   | 0 |
-------------
| B | 0 | 1 |
-------------
| C | 1 | 1 |
-   ---------
|   | 0 | 1 |
-------------
```

is there a way to do it in javascript or is there an easy way to do it in the jsp ?

Comment: I think there's a way in both JavaScript and in JSP.

Comment: @Mansuro no i just reversed them by accident, i'll fix that

Comment: shouldn't the last cells of the last two records be merged? Both contain '1'.

Comment: @isnot2bad no the merged cells go from left to right, if the cells on the lift are different we dont merge the cells

Comment: in JSP, you can use the JSTL with forEach or forTokens

Comment: It looks also JSON ready so you can do it in Javascript

Comment: @RachidO. just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Javascript:

***Source:***

```
var arr = [['A',0,1],['A',0,0],['B',0,1],['C',1,1],['C',0,1]];
```

***Calculate merge depth for each cell:***

```
var depth = arr.map(function(item){
    return item.map(function(){
        return 0;
    });
});

var arrLength = arr.length;
for(var index=0;index<arrLength;index++){

    var subArr = arr[index];
    var subLength = subArr.length;
    var tIndex;
    var maxtIndex = arrLength;

    if(index < arrLength -1) {       
        for(var i=0;i<subLength;i++){
            tIndex = index + 1;
            while(depth[index][i] != -1 && tIndex<maxtIndex){
                if(subArr[i] == arr[tIndex][i]){
                    depth[index][i] = depth[index][i]+1;
                    depth[tIndex][i] = -1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                tIndex++;
                maxtIndex = tIndex;
            }

            if(depth[index][i] == 0){
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

***Result table:***

```
var tableHtml = '<table>' + arr.map(function(subArr, index){
    var str = '<tr>';
        for(var i=0;i<subArr.length;i++){
            var iDepth = depth[index][i];
            if(iDepth !== -1) {
                str += '<td' + (iDepth > 0?' rowspan="'
                             + (iDepth + 1)+'"':'') + '>'
                             +subArr[i]
                     + '</td>';
            }
        }       
    return str+'</tr>';
}).join(' ') + '</table>';
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygu4m/5/)

Answer (score 1):

**updated**
it is working now but still not as you want

```
<script>
    var a = [['A','0','1'],['A','0','0'],['B','0','1'],['C','1','1'],['C','0','1']];     //your array
    var table = document.getElementById('your_table'); //a table to contain the res
    for (i = 0; i< a.length; i++) { //loop for num of rows
    var row = table.insertRow(i); //create the row and pt it in table
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //loop 3 times for colums
            var cell = row.insertCell(j); //create td tag
            if (i == 0)
            cell.innerHTML = a[i][j];
            else {
                if(a[i][j] != a[i-1][j]) { // if the value not equal to the one above
                    cell.innerHTML = a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can do in following way

```
 var numbers = [['A','0','1'],['A','0','0'],['B','0','1'],['C','1','1'],['C','0','1']];

 var rows = "";

 for(var i=0; i < numbers .length; i++){

    rows = rows  + "<tr>"

    for(var j=0; j < 3; j++){

         if(i != '0' && numbers[i][j]==numbers[i-1][j]){
              rows = rows  + "<td>"+"-"+"</td>" 
         }else{
              rows = rows  + "<td>"+numbers[i][j]+"</td>" 
         }
    } 

    rows = rows  + "</tr>"
 }

 var table ="<table>" + rows  +"</table>"
//you can append it to DIV or any element in JSP
```